# Rounded Corner doesn't work on openFileInput Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

The Rounded Corner code works on both Volley NetworkImageView and the resource. But it doesn't work on the Bitmap from ApplicationContext. Here below is the code.

```
public class ImageViewUtils {
    public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, pixels, pixels, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
    }
}


public class Fragment{
     ......
     imageView.setImageBitmap(ImageViewUtils.getRoundedCornerBitmap(((AppContext) getActivity().getApplicationContext()).getUserPhoto(), 10); // The rounded corner doesn't work.

     imageView.setImageBitmap(ImageViewUtils.getRoundedCornerBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_avatar), 10); // The rounded corner works.
     ......
}



public class AppContext extends Application {
    ......
    // Get the Bitmap of a photo.
    public Bitmap getUserPhoto(){

        FileInputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = openFileInput(KEY_USER_PHOTO_FILE_NAME);
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
            return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ball);
        } finally {
            if(in != null) try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
    ......
}
```

Below is the layout of this ImageView

```
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:src="@drawable/ball"
        android:contentDescription="@string/title_activity_profile"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/touchable_height_15"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/touchable_width_15"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

The weird thing is that it works on the resource but it doesn't work on the Bitmap object. This bother me 4 hours. Can someone shed some light?

Comment: What mean "doesn't work"? You see image without rounded corners or you don't see image at all?

Comment: @Divers I can see the image, but I didn't see the rounded corner.

Comment: I think that problem in that your image from sdcard has bigger resolution, that's why 10px corner radius is not enough to have visual effect. Other suggestion is that because of scaleType and other aspect ratio of image from sdcard, corders just cuted by ImageView.

Comment: @Divers You're awesome! The image's resolution is too big. I changed the corner radius to 100dp, the corner was finally rounded. So in case, what I need to do is to get the size of the resolution and add maybe 1/10 of the size to the corner radius. Many thanks!

Comment: I've post an answer with this info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible your image resolution is too high, so 10px round is not visible, try with higher value of corner radius - it should make it visible.